# Remove leading slash fails

Tags: javascript

I have a number of routes that start with `sn_asset_*` for instance `sn_asset_security`. Some of other routes start with `sn_members_*` i.e `sn_members_all`

I am trying to list all routes that start with `sn_asset`. To do that i am taking the current route,removing the starting slash and then search the big array of routes that i have.

I am holding the array of routes this way

```
var all_routes = [];

  var routeName = route.getName();
  var routeTitle = route.options.title;
  var routeIcon = route.options.icon;
  var entry = {
    'name':routeName,
    'title':routeTitle,
    'icon':routeIcon
  };
  all_routes.push(entry);
```

I am able to list the route name,title and icon this way

```
var i, item;
for (i = 0; i < all_routes.length; i++) {
    for (item in all_routes[i]) {
        console.log(item + ": " + all_routes[i][item] + "<br>");
    }
}
```

When i get my current url for instance

```
var values = '/sn_asset_browse';

values.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g, '');

alert(values);

var values = '/sn_asset_browse'.split('_');

var slash = values[0];
var asset = values[1];
var other = values[2];



var sn = slash+'_'+asset;
console.log(slash);
console.log(other);
console.log(asset);
```

i am not able to remove the starting slash therefore i cant even search for routes that start with `sn_asset`.

Comment: Replace (and btw - all string manipulation methods) doesn't work per reference - as such you have to do `values = values.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g, '');`

Comment: You  are missing saving the result. Also you can make it simpler: `values = (values.chartAt(0)=="/") ? values.substring(1):values;`

Comment: Even shorter: `if(values[0]=="/")values=values.slice(1)`

Comment: If you know that the slash is always going to be there, you could just so a substring/slice instead of regex replace.